# Mongoose to postgres Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, mongoose, sequelize.js

I'm new with Sequelize and i have an issue:

How to properly write this code below with sequelize?

1) `default_tags: []` - this line

2) `Category.set()` - this line

```
var mongoose = require('../lib/mongoose')

var Category = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
  },
  description: String,
  default_tags: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tag',
  }],
})

Category.set('toJSON', {
  virtuals: true,
  versionKey: false
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', Category)
```

Comment: First one is about [making an association](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#one-to-many-associations)

Answer (score 0):

I did the first one without an association. That's because I did not want a resulting separate table, as the array would just be used on this specific relation/collection (Category). I also knew I was going to be using Sequelize with Postgres. If you have the luxury of doing Sequelize with Postgres, you can use Postgres composite types:

```
sequelize.query(
        "CREATE TYPE category_tags_type AS (type varchar,ref varchar );"   
     );
```

Then when that has run, you can do

```
const Category = sequelize.define( "category",
     { name: Sequelize.STRING, description: Sequelize.string,
       default_tags: '_category_tags_type'
     }
```

The beginning underscore before category_tags_type tells sequelize this is an array.